# Rebus - Subscribing to Events in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, events, rebus

I have two applications using Rebus in ASP.NET MVC Core 
I am able send messages between two applications using Bus.Send(...). What I can't is to publish event such as CustomerCreated after creating so that other applications can take actions.

I have configured the application as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
     services.AutoRegisterHandlersFromAssemblyOf<Handler1>();
     services.AddRebus(configure => configure
            .Logging(l => l.Use(new MSLoggerFactoryAdapter(_loggerFactory)))
            .Transport(t=>t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672", "rebus_rabbit_first"))
                    .Sagas(x => x.StoreInSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RebusDBRabbit;User ID=student;Password=student;", "Sagas", "SagaIndex"))
                    .Options(o =>
                    {
                        o.SetNumberOfWorkers(10);
                        o.SetMaxParallelism(20);
                        o.HandleMessagesInsideTransactionScope();
                        o.SimpleRetryStrategy(errorQueueAddress: "somewhere_else", maxDeliveryAttempts: 10, secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true);

                     })

                    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
                    .MapAssemblyOf<CreateStudent>("rebus_rabbit_second")));


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

In the Controller I Send a message to another Application as follows

```
CreateStudent student = new CreateStudent { StudentID="90008", StudentName="Amour Rashid Hamad",DateOfBirth=DateTime.Parse("1974-03-18") };
_bus.Send(student).Wait();
```

This is OK.
Now My Problem is to publish an event to broadcast the event to other interested parties eg

```
 _bus.Publish(new StudentCreated { StudentID="90008",Remarks="Hurray We have been Successfully"});
```

How Do I Subscribe to the event as per my configuration. I have seen some samples but I could not understand them. Adding to my implementation would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

In the Service Configuration I did as follows:

```
app.ApplicationServices.UseRebus(async bus => {
  await bus.Subscribe<StudentCreated>();
            });
```

and then created a handler

```
public class StudentCreatedEventHandler : IHandleMessages<StudentCreated>, IHandleMessages<IFailed<StudentCreated>>
    {
        readonly IBus _bus;

        public StudentCreatedEventHandler(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        public async Task Handle(StudentCreated student)
        {
            // do stuff that can fail here...
            var remarks = $"Remarks on RebusWithRabbit1 : {student.Remarks}";

        }

        public async Task Handle(IFailed<StudentCreated> failedMessage)
        {
            await _bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
}
```

This could handle the events published.
I just want to get assured if that is the proper way of doing it.

I have however noticed one thing. If I have more than one endpoints Subscribing to the event only one is notified. I expected that multiple endpoints could need to be notified and every one may execute a different process from the same event.

Is there any way to change this behavior. I remember in MassTransit this is the default behavious.
Thanks

Comment: When you subcsribe to an event, you're binding the topic to the subscriber's input queue. If you have two distinct subscribers, they should have different input queue names, and then they will each get a copy of the event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `await bus.Send(...)` properly.

As you've probably figured out, `Send` looks up a destination queue and sends to that (and only that), and the lookup is done from the endpoint mappings (where you're currently mapping all message types to the queue named `rebus_rabbit_second`).

When you want to `await bus.Publish(...)`, you need someone to `await bus.Subscribe<T>()` accordingly. Underneath the covers, Rebus will use the .NET type as the topic, so if you

```cs
await bus.Subscribe<SomeEvent>();
```

in one application, and

```cs
await bus.Publish(new SomeEvent());
```

in another, your subscriber will receive the event.

**TL;DR**: You need to

```cs
await bus.Subscribe<StudentCreated>();
```

in the application where you want to receive published events of type `StudentCreated`.

---

Btw. you should EITHER use C#'s support for calling asynchronous methods

```cs
await bus.Send(yourMessage);
```

or invoke Rebus' synchronous API to do your work:

```cs
var syncBus = bus.Advances.SyncBus;

syncBus.Send(yourMessage); //< returns void
```

Rebus' synchronous methods do not deadlock the thread, e.g. if you're calling them from ASP.NET or WCF.